# Scraping forums with scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrap some forums with scrapy and store the data in a database. But I don't know to do it efficiently when it comes to updating the database. This is what my spider looks like:

```
class ForumSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = "forum"
allowed_domains= ["forums.example.com"]
start_urls = ["forums.example.com/index.php"]
rules = (
       Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'/forum?id=\d+',)), 
        follow=True,   callback='parse_index'),
    )

def parse_index(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    #parsing....looking for threads.....
    #pass the data to pipeline and store in to the db....
```

My problem is when I scrap the same forum again, say a week later, there is no point to go through all the pages, because the new threads or any threads with new post would be on top of other inactive threads. My idea is to check the first pages of a forum(forums.example.com/forum?id=1), if it found a thread with the same URL and the same number of reply on page one. There is no point to go to the second page. So the spider should proceed to another forum(forums.example.com/forum?id=2). I tried modifying the start_urls and rules, but it seemed like they are not responding once the spider is running. Is there a way to do it in scrapy?

My second problem is how to use different pipeline for different spiders. I found something on stack overflow. But it seems like scrapy isn't built to do this, it seems like you suppose to create a new project for different sites.

Am I using the wrong tool to do this? Or I am missing something. I thought about using mechanize and lxml to do it. But I need to implement twisted and unicode handling and so on which makes me want to stick with scrapy

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is to create a http requests on fly.

Inside the parse_index function do this.
`request = self.make_requests_from_url(http://forums.example.com/forum?id=2)

  return request`

If you want to submit multiple http requests return a array.
See this [Request in scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request)

You are right about the second thing, you are suppose to write different spiders if you want to extract different type of data from different websites.